# ¿Cómo convertir cada elemento de tipo string de un array a lowercase en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy realizando una función para encontrar un nombre en específico dado un conjunto de nombres metidos en un Array, si ese nombre se encuentra dentro del Array, quiero que me devuelva su posición, en caso contrario, quiero que me retorne -1.

Quiero que mi función pueda localizar ese nombre independientemente de si está escrito todo en mayúscula o minúscula pero, al intentar de pasar cada nombre dentro del Array a lowercase, el navegador me arroja un warning que dice: "Array to string conversion" y no entiendo el motivo.

Agradecería si alguien pudiese explicarme el por qué de este warning si lo que convierto a lowercase sería cada elemento del Array y no el Array como tal.

Dejo mi código por si sirva.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
<?php

function findBob($names)
{

    $namesToLower = [];

    foreach ($names as $name) {
        array_push($namesToLower, strtolower($name));
    }

    echo $namesToLower;

    $position = array_search('bob', $namesToLower);

    $position
        ? $position = array_search('bob', $namesToLower)
        : $position = -1;

    echo $position;
}

findBob(['marta', 'ruben', 'LUCIA', 'BOB']);
```

Comment: `$namesToLower` es un array, por tanto no puedes hacer esto: `echo $namesToLower`. Para mostrar arrays debes usar `var_dump` o `print_r`, no `echo`. Aparte de eso, tu código es redundante y podría simplificarse bastante. ¿Esto es un ejercicio y te han dicho que debe hacerse del modo en que lo estás haciendo?

Comment: @A.Cedano, tenes toda la razón. Me pasé buscando errores en mi lógica y olvidé eso, te agradezco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error aquí es que `$nameToLower` es un array, y los arrays no se imprimen con `echo`.

Puedes usar `print_r()` o `var_dump()` para mostrarlos o mediante una lectura dentro de un bucle.

Ahora bien leyendo esto:

> Estoy realizando una función para encontrar un nombre en específico
> dado un conjunto de nombres metidos en un Array, si ese nombre se
> encuentra dentro del Array, quiero que me devuelva su posición, en
> caso contrario, quiero que me retorne -1.

Tu función podría simplificarse. Por un lado, repites `array_search` sin necesidad. Por otro lado, puedes usar `array_map()` para pasar todos los valores del array a minúscula, **si fuera necesario guardar una referencia al array convertido**, de no ser así puedes hacerlo directamente (ver comentario en el código). Por otro lado, puedes simplificar con un ternario la obtención de `$position`.

La función quedaría así:

```
function findBod($names)
{

    /*
        Esto es para convertir todo a minúscula, si es necesario
    */
    $namesToLower = array_map('strtolower', $names);
    
    /*
        Usamos un ternario para hacer lo que indicas 
        en el enunciado de la pregunta
    */
    $position = array_search('bob', $namesToLower) ?: -1;
    /*
        Si no necesitas una referencia al array
        con sus valores en minúscula
        puedes prescindir de la creación de $namesToLower
        y cambiar la línea anterior por esto:
        $position = array_search('bob', array_map('strtolower', $names)) ?: -1;
        y quitar el print_r que sigue, por supuesto ....
    */
    print_r( $namesToLower);
    echo $position;
}
```

Hagamos dos pruebas:

```
findBod(['marta', 'ruben', 'LUCIA', 'BOB']);
```

**Salida:**

```
3
```

---

```
findBod(['marta', 'ruben', 'LUCIA', 'BOBs']);
```

**Salida:**

```
-1
```

#### Post-Data

Está de más decir que una función como esta debería evolucionar, para no encuentre sólo a `Bob` sino a cualquier otro. De modo que `findBob()` pasaría a llamarse `findAny()`, y que incorporaría un segundo parámetro que sería el nombre de la persona a buscar.

El método se definiría así:

```
findAny($names, $theName) {

    # ...
    #Esta línea cambia
    $position = array_search($theName, array_map('strtolower', $names)) ?: -1;
    # ...

}
```

Y la llamada sería:

```
findAny(['marta', 'ruben', 'LUCIA', 'BOB'], 'marta');
```

Como ves, serviría para Bob, para Marta y para cualquiera.

Comment: Muy buena tu recomendación para simplificar el código, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

el echo imprime un string y literalmente le estas pasando un array, tienes que acceder a los indices del array para poder hacer un echo

```
echo $namesToLower[0];
```

Este código funcionara:

```
<?php

function findBod($names)
{

    $namesToLower = [];

    foreach ($names as $name) {
        array_push($namesToLower, strtolower($name));
    }

    echo $namesToLower[0];

    $position = array_search('bob', $namesToLower);

    $position
        ? $position = array_search('bob', $namesToLower)
        : $position = -1;

    echo $position;
}

findBod(['marta', 'ruben', 'LUCIA', 'BOB']);
```

Comment: Excelente, ¡muchas gracias por tu ayuda!